# The arrow key outputs `^[[A`、`^[[B`、`^[[C`、`^[[D` strings in tmux + oh-my-zsh?

Tags: zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

In some circumstances, when I input arrow keys it will outputs string `^[[A`、`^[[B`、`^[[C`、`^[[D` into screen. I am using tmux and oh-my-zsh environment.

The circumstances includes:

- Start a server and the pane in tmux is working for a continuously running process. When the server enter a breakpoint I use the `up` arrow key to find the previous history, but the screen outputs `^[[A` string.

Why and how to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

In short, that is exactly what the computer sees as sent from your keyboard.

You actually need some utilities like the `readline` library in bash to convert the character sequences, e.g. `^[[D` to cursor-moving actions, e.g. <kbd>←</kbd>. Quite often this has been provided and we just take it as granted.

---

Unlike <kbd>Esc</kbd> (`0x1B`), <kbd>Space</kbd> (`0x20`), or
<kbd>Del</kbd> (`0x7F`), there are no special ASCII values designated for
arrow keys, which were invented pretty late in the computer history.

When you press an arrow key, what the keyboard actually sends is a sequence
of combinations. One type of popular combinations is

| Arrow Key | Control Sequence Introducer (CSI) |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>↑</kbd> | <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> |
| <kbd>↓</kbd> | <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> |
| <kbd>→</kbd> | <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> |
| <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> |

The <kbd>ESC</kbd> key (ASCII value `27` in dec, `033` in oct, or `0x1B` in hex) is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, shown as `^[`.

Therefore, what you saw was what your keyboard actually sent. You pressed <kbd>←</kbd>, and the computer received <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, which was exactly `^[[D`.

Comment: And why zsh in tmux outputs `^[[D` but normal zhs and bash(including bash in tmux) get the right arrow left action?